# 16.04 froze up and didn't install

Tags: boot, 16.04

The Ubuntu 16.04 update on my Samsung netbook froze and I had to reboot the computer. Now I can only go as far as choosing the Ubuntu installation and can go as far as "end Kernel panic". Is there a way to restore the files on the system? I used this machine as a "backup" computer!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer from the same drive you've used to install.

From there, using the file manager, you can see the amount of damage caused and try to recover anything.

Comment: Thanks but I can't load the system.
The system wasn't installed properly.

Comment: Why? If you can't boot anything there's no way we can help.

Comment: I just installed ubuntu on the virtualbox and connected the hard drive with the system that doesn't boot after the failed install.
It sees only a 255mb volume with the grub folder and a bunch of files.
Is there anyway to install a system on that volume and then see if I can boot it up?

Comment: Which system are you currently using?

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. At the moment, Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on Windows 10 Home.
The other computer - the one that failed to update - ran Xubuntu 15.

Comment: You can either burn the ISO image directly to the HDD (so it would become a Live, bootable drive) or use `bootstrap` to install a base Ubuntu system in your HDD through VirtualBox's Ubuntu. Your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Will it preserve my files when I boot it? Presumably, it will want to install the new system when I power it up...

Comment: If you use the first method all files will be lost. The second one will keep them. I'm not really sure about VirtualBox + bootstrap, but it should work fine.